# Should I use the FQN in PHPDoc if I'm importing the class with use?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Let's say I have a `UserController` class and I'm importing the `App\User` class with `use`. Inside, there is a `show()` method that receieves an instance of `User`.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show user info
     * 
     * @param  User $user
     * @return Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Is it recommended to add the fully qualified name of `User` in PHPDoc even if I'm importing the class with `use`?

Comment: The entire point of importing the class is that you *don't* have to use the fully qualified name. That's all it does.

Comment: ... *"you don't have to use the fully qualified name **in the code**."* `use` doesn't affect the comments. The question is about *if* and *how* PHPDoc uses the `use` declarations.

Comment: It applies to both the code and the PHPDoc blocks - anything that's parsing the phpdoc comment programmatically should take the `use` statements into account. Any editor I've used in the last few years does, at least, as do tools like PHPDocumentor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use FQN if there are no `use` statement, as it would be recognized as a different class, in Your case as `\JsonResponse` which is not imported.

As for `User` class, use short name.

It is more convenient to import class with `use` statement and write short name in docblock.

Also class aliases can be used, for instance:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show user info
     * 
     * @param  User $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        // Do something...
    }

}
```

Comment: So PHPDoc is smart enough to understand that the `User` class is being imported with `use` so I don't need to use the FQN?

Comment: It depends on tool used, it is understood by PHP IDE's like Netbeans, Eclipse, PhpStorm, as well as documentation generators like phpDocumentor and apigen.

Comment: @Camilo PHPDoc itself isn't "smart" at all. It's just a formatting convention for comments. Whether your IDE (or whatever else is actually parsing the comment and doing something with it) is a separate issue. Most tools (in my experience at least), will take `use` statements into account.

Comment: I've also added note about class aliases.

Comment: @iainn You are right, I was more concerned about the phpDocumentor if it would be "smart enough".